# Microsoft login Infinte loading

Tags: react-native, authentication, outlook

When i enter email for login in microsoft then the app start loading
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0f7e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfR24.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9RIR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wt2l.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT9Jz.png)

i am try to login with microsoft by using react-native-azure-auth

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Update your question with a minimum reproducible example as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask